# Create UI on top of google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-sheets-query

I have a google sheet with some data, say Roll Number and Name. Now I want to create UI for the google sheet with an text box name and have option search

When I enter name and click search, I should get all the records with that particular name.

How do I achieve this in google sheet? Any addons or scripts available?

Answer (score 1):

Google Drive has a [full featured API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/) so you can consume its data from any application, in nearly any technology (Python, Javascript, PHP etc) using its Rest API.

I'm pretty sure no addons available from market to do it, so the solution would be to implement it yourself.